# Curve fitting error in python

Tags: python, matlab

I have been trying to do curve fitting using python giving x and y values, but unfortunately I am not getting the 
curve in the way i wanted. I  also tried to fit(exponential) the same x,y values in matlab and i am getting the exact curve. 
The problems is that the coefficients returned by python code is not the same as returned by matlab thus generating a different curve.
Please help me with a way to find the correct coefficient values.
I have attached the code below.

```
#CODE
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import math


n=13.75;

x=[0.375,2.125/4.85714,(2.125/5.6667), (2.125/11.33), (2.125/34),0]
y=[0,n/6.111, (n)/3.0555, (n)/2.24489, (n)/2.03708, (n)/1.96428];


#x = np.linspace(0,4,50) # Example data

def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.exp(b * x) + c * np.exp(d * x)

#y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5) # Example exponential data

# Here you give the initial parameters for a,b,c which Python then iterates over
# to find the best fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x,y,p0=(0.17273307092464,0.050942379680265,0,0.050942379680265), method='trf')

print(popt) # This contains your three best fit parameters

p5 = popt[0] # This is your a
p6 = popt[1] # This is your b
p7 = popt[2] # This is your c
p8 = popt[3] # This is your d



yy=np.linspace(0,(n)/1.96428,50);
xx=p5 * np.exp(p6 * yy) + p7 * np.exp(p8 * yy)
plt.plot(yy,xx)
plt.scatter(y,x, c='b',label='The data points')
plt.show()
```

Comment: are you using the same method trf in Matlab, because if not, for non-constrained optimization, Matlab will use lm. Use 'lm' here and check the results

Comment: I tried lm, dogbox too, but no  change is happening

Comment: I am getting different values for lm and trf and for DogBox it doesn't converge. for lm => [ 4.09497619 -2.64826965  3.55134273 -2.64870059]; for trf => [ 3.96734255 -2.64836956  3.67899724 -2.64865223]

Comment: Thank you for you effort in helping me. :)  .Now coming to the point the coefficients are different for both lm and trf, but the curve being plotted in both cases is not the required curve

Comment: I don't have access to matlab, so can't check what is the answer from matlab

Comment: The actual coefficients generated in matlab are p5 =4.296 p6 = 0.2212 p7 = -3.916  p8 = 0.2344